# How to transform a string "28 JUN 2013" in another string "2013-06-28"

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I need a method which takes a date with the month in letters like "January" or "JAN" and finds its correspondent "01".

Can you give me any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this in VB.NET, but here's one way you can do this in C#...   DateTime.Parse("28 JUN 2013").ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")

Comment: So basically, use DateTime.Parse - should be the same for VB.NET

Comment: @series0ne the vb.net is identical

Comment: @user1937198, Ah...well that's good then! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As simple as using `DateTime.Parse`

```
 DateTime val = DateTime.ParseExact("28 JUN 2013", "dd MMM yyyy", null)
```

*Note: you may not need ParseExact if this date format is default understood, which I believe it is. So this should work as well in your case, and it would also handle other default uses:

```
DateTime val = DateTime.Parse("28 JUN 2013")
```

If you have several non-standard date conversions to support you may need to try several `DateTime.ParseExact` options in a if/else if loop or try/catch block.

**Note Andrew M's comment for a better approach to multiple formats:** *There's an overload of DateTime.ParseExact which takes an array of formats: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853.aspx – Andrew Morton*

The full month format string would look like:

```
DateTime val = DateTime.ParseExact("28 January 2013", "dd MMMM yyyy", null)
```

Note the extra `M`. See here for format string info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: There's an overload of DateTime.ParseExact which takes an array of formats: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853.aspx